# Spark SQL create an array with array values in a column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-sql

I have a column of type integer arrays:

```
 case class Testing(name: String, age: Int, salary: Double, array: Array[Int])

  val x = sc.parallelize(Array(
     Testing(null, 21, 905.33, Array(1,2,3)),
     Testing("Noelia", 26, 1130.60, Array(3,2,1)),
     Testing("Pilar", 52,  1890.85, Array(3,3,3)),
     Testing("Roberto", 31, 1450.14, Array(1,0,0))
   ))

  // Convert RDD to a DataFrame 
  val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(x) 

  // For SQL usage we need to register the table
   df.registerTempTable("df")
```

I want to create an array whose elements are the values ​​of the column "array". How to do this in Spark SQL?

```
 sqlContext.sql("SELECT [array] from df").show

 [ [1,2,3], [3,2,1], [3,3,3], [1,0,0]]
```

Comment: I think you are missing code. Assuming you really are talking about Spark SQL, you need a step where you create a DataFrame.

Comment: It is understood that better?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming as you imply that you have a `DataFrame` named `df`, and that the `Array()` values are in a column named `array` this should do the trick.

```
df.select($"array").rdd.map{
  row =>  row.getList[Int](0).toArray
}.collect()
```

Of if you want to do it through `sqlContext.sql`:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT array FROM df").rdd.map{
  row =>  row.getList[Int](0).toArray
}.collect()
```

Comment: There some way to do this through a function udf ?

Comment: If so it would do exactly this same logic in a `udf`. One way or another you have to convert a `DataFrame` to an `Array[Array[Int]]`. Which means `DataFrame` -> `RDD[Row]` -> `RDD[Array[Int]]` -> `Array[Array[Int]]`

Comment: Sorry but I'm new and I do not see how . Say I want something like: `sqlContext.sql("select agg(array1, array2, array3) from df")`. 
As I can define a function like this?

Comment: You can do `sqlContext.sql("SELECT array[0] as array1, array[1] as array2, array[2] as array3 FROM df")` -- does that help?

Comment: No, I want to pass the array you've created with your code in a UDF funtion , as I do that?